# What does the Freestyle Diffuse Color Modifier do?

Tags: freestyle

I can't find any info on it. Anyone know what it does? Really curious.

[image: this fella]

Comment: As it says - it should mix the base color of your line with the diffuse color of the object the line is drawn on. Does it not?

Comment: I thought so as well, but I keep getting white lines, regardless of what color the material or freestyle lines are.

Comment: Huh, that's funny. I experimented a bit and found it only to work when "use nodes" is disabled in the material. Seems like a relic from good old Blender Internal-times?

Comment: Oh that's interesting. Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, you should at least be able to set the line color as parameter in the material and mix this with your base color. AFAIK this only gives you one solid color per material, though, without texture.